# I have designed a footer in Bootstrap 4. It's well in desktop version. But in mobile version it does not come in center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```css
.footer_img{

 padding-left: 30px;
 width:170px;
 height:63px;
 align-self: center;
}

.footer{
 margin-bottom: 41px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer container">
     
  <div class="clearfix">
   <span class="float-left"><a href="#"><img class="footer_img" src="images/logo.png"></a></span>
   <span class="float-right">&copy; XYZABC Inc and Affiliates.All Rights Reserved</span>
  </div>

 </div>
```

In desktop version, the footer stays all right and when I do responsive or check in mobile, the logo and the company name don't stay in center. I have designed the footer using bootstrap 4 but I'm new to it. Can someone explain it to me how this is to be done. I have also attached a screenshot in the question.

[image: desktop version]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add these lines of code in your css to achieve the desired result.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:640px){
   .footer{text-align:center;}
   .footer .float-left,
   .footer .float-right{float:none;display:inline-block;clear:both;width:100%;}    
}
```

You may change the max-width according to your requirement. it will be applied on all the screen below it (ie. mobile screen).